# adobe reader, .pdf, черная иконка документа

Tags: windows, adobe

Люди добрые, подскажите.
Мне для работы необходимо отображать содержимое файлов .pdf в виде эскизов заместо иконки.
В целом все работает, но на рабочем столе значок файла превращается в черный квадратик, это как-то лечится?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При изменении размеров иконок рабочего стола через Ctrl+колесико, +1 вверх -1 вниз, иконки появляются, после первого обновления рабочего стола они остаются, но после второго обновления почему-то опять слетают.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй удалить thumbs.db с рабочего стола, чтоб пересоздался эскиз.

Comment: eri, там нет такого файла, может в другой директории?

Comment: Он скрытый системный

Comment: я включил отображение скрытых и системных файлов, его там нет

Comment: надо почитать куда переместили его в новой винде...

Comment: через очистку диска сделал, удалил эскизы, аналогично до второго обновления.

Answer (score 0):

Нашлось решение:
Правой кнопкой мыши по свободному месту рабочего стола --> Вид --> Крупные/Обычные/Мелкие переключить.
Если размер через Ctrl+колесико мыши не менять, то слетать не будут.
Недочет со стороны adobe, не предусмотрели что в Windows есть возможность менять размеры иконок на рабочем столе.